Pass parameters to Laravel route group
I'm using the latest versions of Laravel, React, and Inertia as my primary technologies. I'm developing a website that has "categories" in its header, which are processed by an Eloquent query. My goal is to pass this array of categories to a group of routes so that I can render the appropriate header in them. As I'm relatively new to Laravel, I'm unsure if I can accomplish this with Controllers or Middleware. I know I can use Inertia's shared data, but I want to have this array just in a group of routes.
I attempted to create a middleware and use it in web.php, but without success.
Here's my CategoryMiddleware.php:
class CategoryMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $categories = Category::with('children.children')->whereNull('parent_id')->get();
        view()->share('categories', $categories);
        return $next($request);
    }
}

And a part of my web.php:
Route::middleware(['category'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return Inertia::render('Shop/Home');
    })->name('home');
});

I've registered the middleware like this in Kernel.php:
protected $middlewareAliases = [
    .
    .
    .
    'category' => \App\Http\Middleware\CategoryMiddleware::class,
];


You're sharing the variable correctly using the view()->share() call. However, you need to put that inside the boot() method of a service provider, for example, App\Providers\AppServiceProviders. Here's an example:
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        $categories = Category::with('children.children')->whereNull('parent_id')->get();
        view()->share('categories', $categories);
    }
}



Thanks for your answer. Sorry if I'm not Laravel expert, but I think this variable would be accessible for all routes not a defined group of routes. In this way I'll simply use Inertia's shared data instead.
Please let me know how to use this variable in my React nested components and what I should do to my routes if anything needed.
